# How to use Excel's LENGTH function for an entire column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need help in using `MAX(LENGTH)` Excel formula to find the minimum length needed to accommodate my existing data. I have a sheet of more than 200k rows to import to a newly designed database.

The sheet contains GDPR-sensitive information but I can show here just a few cells with numeric identifier that do not cause harm

[image: Excel file]

I need to find the `MAX` `LENGTH` of every cell in each column separately.

I tried to start with `B` column. I put myself into a blank cell, and typed (this Excel uses [Mr. Dante Alighier's native language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Language))

```
=MAX(LUNGHEZZA(B:B))
=MAX(LEN(B:B))
```

The returned value was 7. But please look at cell `B9` (`0304000790`): it has 10 characters.

What is wrong in my formula computation? I have looked around the Internet but the formula recommended by others is the same I'm trying here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEN` is expected to work on one cell, not many.

In order to make it work on many cells, you must enter it as an *array* formula. Enter the formula not using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, but a combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This "encapsulates" the formula in curly braces `{=....}` .

Note that array formulas are not clever enough not to include empty cells at the bottom of your file, if you passed the whole column to the formula. In this case it may be very slow, because it will loop and calculate lengths of every cell, even empty and not used ones at the bottom. You may want to limit your passed column size, e.g. `=MAX(LEN($B$2:$B$200000))` .

Comment: The braces worked great